# why does strcmp() not work for my array inputs?

Tags: arrays, c, strcmp

I am using strtok() and using Strcmp() to compare the tokens. I notice that strcmp() only works when I put a literal to compare. For example strcmp(token,"A") as opposed to the char array strcmp(token,inputs[count]). Can someone help me get it to recognize the array element? One main problem I have is that strcmp keeps grouping element "A" and element "B" as the same. But when I put the string literals instead of the array element equivalent my code works. My code is below.

```
char inputs[numberOfInputs][30];
 for(int i = 0;i < numberOfInputs;i++){
        fscanf(fp,"%s",inputs[i]);
 }
char *token = strtok(temp," ");
while(token!=null){
     for(inputCount = 0; inputCount < numberOfInputs; inputCount++){
        if(strcmp(token, inputs[inputCount]) == 0){
           token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        else if(strcmp(token, inputs[inputCount]) == 0){
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
```

Comment: Also what does contain `inputs[inputCount]`? Is it a null-terminated string?

Comment: whoever is trying to edit the post pls wait, he has already messed up one of my beautiful edit, and he is going to edit the post again.

Comment: @Julian Romero The if statement does not make a sense. And it seems you are using an uninitialized array.

Comment: the `if` and `else` both does the same test

Comment: Watch out for the trailing newline if you are inputting with `fgets()`.

Comment: There is no such thing as empty array in C. Please don't describe the missing parts in English prose, post a [mcve] instead.

Comment: It is unclear what the code is attempting. It makes the same comparison twice, with the same action in both cases.

Comment: just added strcmp. Also inputs is a char array that has given strings. So the for loop is suppose to go through the array list and match only input values.

Comment: Are the strings in `inputs` null-terminated?

Comment: @stark I believe they are not. How would i do this?

Comment: Show how you re initializing `inputs` That's the reason why we always want a complete example.

Comment: If `strcmp` tells you the strings are different,. the _are_ different.

Comment: @stark i edited it. I believe it shows how its initialized

Comment: @JulianRomero we need a [MCVE] here.

Comment: Yes.  %s strings should be null-terminated.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't match?  You don't do anything when you find a match.

Comment: @stark how would i do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost sure your problem is reading the input. You haven't provided information about the input file format.

To make sure the problem isn't the one I described try initializing the array instead of reading from the file first. Something like this:

```
 char inputs[numberOfInputs][30] = {"value1", "value2", "value3"};
```

If after doing this change your code work the way you want, check the documentation for **fscanf** with **%s** and see if your input is compatible with that.

Comment: Yeah thats not the issue my array elements are {A, B} which is what they're suppose to be. It keeps recognizing "A" and "B" as the same string. I have no idea how. But with the literal it says its different.

Comment: Well, your code is a little confusing. You are checking the same condition twice, hence you are never going to update token if it is not in the inputs and it will lead to an infinite loop... maybe you should describe what you are trying to do